# URL /testform handler does not match any handler

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a simple form that receives an input from the user and respond by displaying same input on the webpage using python2.7 and Google app engine running locally.Using SublimeText. I'm getting errors **"*HTTP ERROR 500*"** and tried to solve it as shown below but no luck.

This is the app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
script: test.app
```

This is the test file:

```
import webapp2
form="""
<form action="/testform">
<input  name= "q">
<input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)

class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        q = self.resquest.get("q")
        self.response.out.write(q)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/testform', TestHandler)], debug=True)
```

When I run the file above I receive this message:

> The url "/testform" does not match any handlers.

I already try including a separate handler for the /testform URL:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  script: test.app
- url: /testform
  script: test.app
```

When I do that then I receive the following message:

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I also try changing / to .* and also to /.* on the app.yaml file to handle all URL's like this:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: test.app
```

and:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: test.app
```

Having the same result:

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Your `url: /` pattern in `app.yaml` will cause that, the `url: .*` one should work. Also try restarting the development server after the change, it *might* not always pick up the change. Watch your indentation, too, both in app.yaml and your test file (unless it's just a copy-paste error). If the problem persist show the matching request entry in the dev server log.

Comment: Typo in your code: `resquest` vs `request`. But that's good news - you're past the `does not match any handlers` problem.

Comment: I changed the URL to url: .* as per your suggestion, run the server and passed jj to the input box, when hitting submit button this is what the server returns:                                                                                                             file " /Users/xxxx/Desktop/test/test.py", line 31, in get
    q = self.resquest.get("q")                                                                               AttributeError: 'TestHandler' object has no attribute 'resquest'
INFO     2018-02-20 22:28:00,834 module.py:835] default: "GET /testform?q=jj HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: excellent, I just changed the typo and everything is running smooth.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer to not leave the question hanging.

In the initial version of you `app.yaml` file you only have one handler with the `url: /` pattern. The `/testform` request doesn't match this single handler, which explains the initial error message:

> The url "/testform" does not match any handlers.

All subsequent attempts went OK from handler mapping prospective (I'd go for the `url: .*` one as it's shorter, but that's just a personal preference, any of them should do), the error message actually changed into:

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

But this error has a different root cause - the `resquest` vs `request` typo in the (now properly mapped) `TestHandler.get()` method.